# How to reformat all the files in the project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Reformat code is a very useful feature, but I have a big project where I need to reformat all the files (about 100). How to do this without opening every file and reformatting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right click on the root folder of the project, select "Reformat Code..." and click Run.  You may also hit Ctrl+Alt+L.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work for me. It simply ignores Java files